# How can Tutanota, ProtonMail and Hushmail all claim to provide privacy when they only allow privacy-incompatible payment options?

Tags: privacy, email

I'm attempting to register an e-mail account without destroying my privacy. The reason is simply that one is necessary to be able to register on a different service (web host for my new, very non-shady business venture).

Tutanota, ProtonMail and Hushmail are apparently the only (serious-looking) services in existence which *advertise* or *claim* some sort of "privacy".

At first, and for the longest time until recently, I foolishly tried to get one for free. Turns out that all three flat-out block all VPN and Tor connections, which in turn are necessary for even *theoretical* privacy (but still probably isn't nearly enough).

Please don't tell me that you managed to register one; I've tried countless times over an extended period of time, and they *consistently* refuse, or display a "verify with phone" screen. (No, it's not possible to get a "burner phone" with one's privacy intact where I live.) And even if it works once in a million tries, it's insanity to sit there day and night and just keep filling out the registration forms and trying over and over, only to *possibly* get through once. That's not efficient use of one's time and energy.

So, eventually, I forgot all about ever again getting a free e-mail account, and instead tried **paying** them money.

All three services do not support Bitcoin. It sounds like a joke or something I'm making up, but you are actually forced to fundamentally violate your privacy by using a pay card (Visa/Mastercard) or PayPal.

Tutanota claims to be "working on it" (Bitcoin support, that is), but the problem is that they've been "working on it" for a number of years now and clearly aren't very interested in supporting it. In spite of accepting *donations* via Bitcoin. Even if they at some point in the future start accepting Bitcoin, that doesn't help me *now*.

I will refrain from commenting further on the fact that they *also* seem to not support IMAP or any kind of API for fetching new e-mails from your account and to send new ones, even for "business" accounts, which is an absolute *must* if you, like me, use a self-coded or even just local/native e-mail client and want to automate some things for your business/service.

How is it possible that even these few self-proclaimed "privacy-conscious" e-mail services are literally impossible to use without violating your privacy? Has the concept of "privacy" been eroded so completely as to truly no longer hold any meaning whatsoever?

I tried asking them all about this and got very short and vague responses which suggest to me that they would rather not talk about it.

It does sound like a joke, but I literally cannot even *pay money* to get an e-mail account.

Comment: They're claiming privacy in that you reveal your identity to the email provider, and they keep it private from people you email. Keeping your identity secret from the provider is definitely more secure but I've no experience doing that.

Comment: This is more a rant and not a real question. I propose to close it as off-topic.

Comment: You are confusing "privacy" with "anonymity". And you are assuming that all claims they make are global and complete in scope. You need to understand the scope and context of their statements.

Comment: And you failed to understand the Protonmail link that was provided to you or read it properly. It clearly states that you need to create a free account, then upgrade, and then you use Bitcoin. The screenshot you uploaded was for when you set up a premium account at the start.

Answer (score 4):

Protonmail accepts bitcoin.  See https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/paying-with-bitcoin/.

Protonmail also has a .onion site that is accessible through Tor.  See https://protonmail.com/tor.